What is the difference between a Jivanmukta And a Siddha?
Is there any difference between these stages of realization/enlightenment?

A Siddha is an elevated-being who has attained one or more perfections which could be spiritual, material, or a combination of both.
Some examples of the (material) Siddhis possessed by the Siddhas are:

Vaka-siddhi (speaking about the future)
Vaihāyasa (flying in space)
Kāvya-siddhi (ability to compose highly evolved spiritual poetry)
Manaḥ-java (traveling at the speed of mind)
Parakāya-praveśa (the ability to enter another's body)
Dūra-grahaṇa (the ability to perceive things far, far away), and others.

The residents of the astral worlds like Siddha-loka or Deva-loka are also called as Siddhas since they possess Siddhis such as the above by birth. However, they may or may not be fully self-realized i.e., Jivan-Mukta. Here's an example of the usage of the term Siddha where Lord Kapila is termed as siddha-gaṇādhīśaḥ or the head of all the Siddhas.

अयं सिद्धगणाधीश: साङ्ख्याचार्यै: सुसम्मत: । लोके कपिल इत्याख्यां गन्ता
ते कीर्तिवर्धन: ॥ १९ ॥
ayaṁ siddha-gaṇādhīśaḥ sāṅkhyācāryaiḥ susammataḥ loke kapila ity
ākhyāṁ gantā te kīrti-vardhanaḥ
Your son will be the head of all the Siddhas (perfected souls). He
will be approved by the ācāryas expert in disseminating real
knowledge, and among the people He will be celebrated by the name
Kapila. As the son of Devahūti, He will increase your fame (Shrimad Bhagavatam 3.24.19).

Jivan-Muktas are those who've already crossed beyond the material platform and realized the self while living in their present body. They may or may not possess the above opulences.
Jivan-Muktas are also called Siddhas because they've attained spiritual perfections such as attaining a spiritual body (Siddha-deha) for eternally residing in the spiritual planets of Lord Shiva, Lord Vishnu, or Shakti or merging oneself into cosmic consciousness.
In summary, a Siddha may or may not be a Jivana-Mukta but a Jivana-Mukta is the topmost Siddha.

Thanks for the reply. Where can I read more about this? "...attaining a spiritual body (Siddha-deha) for eternally residing in the spiritual planets of Lord Shiva, Lord Vishnu, or Shakti or merging oneself into cosmic consciousness." Mainly about these planets.

For Vaishnavas, these planets are Vaikuntha / Goloka. For Shaktas, they're Manidveepa / Chintamani Griha. For Shaivites, Kailasha. Advanced yogis constantly meditate on one or more of the respective deities & their planets through Samyama (Dharana + Dhyana + Samadhi) and attain suitable spiritual bodies. Upon exiting their physical body, they enter into these planets.  You can search the above names of these planets and know more about them. Hope it helps.
